# Test for normality with outliers produces strange p-values

Tags: r, normal-distribution, outliers

I try to create some example that show how an outlier causes non-normality. Therefore I created two datasets:

A dataset with normal distributed data

```
 x <- rnorm(100, 3, .25)
```

A dataset with outliers

```
 y <- append(x, c(3,3,3,3))
```

However, when I perform an ad.test for normality I get strange p values.

```
> ad.test(x)

Anderson-Darling normality test

data:  x
A = 0.21369, p-value = 0.8477

> ad.test(y)

Anderson-Darling normality test

data:  y
A = 0.18022, p-value = 0.9135
```

I would assume that my first p-value is below 0.05 (confirming the hypothesis that the data is normally distributed) and the second one is higher.

Any thoughts on where I go wrong?

Comment: How do you define "outlier"? I cannot imagine any situation where value equal to the *expected value* can be considered as outlier.

Comment: Your assumption is the wrong way round I think. But as @tim suggests reading the documentation for rnorm will help here.

Comment: *which* ad.test are you using? The one in nortest? The one in ADGofTest? Some other one? (It *matters*, since the nortest and ADGofTest implementations actually test different hypotheses!)

Comment: The fact that the p value goes up when extra values at the mean are added suggests that the hypothesis for your ad.test is that the data comes from a normal distribution.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your outliers were actually *inliers*. You generated from a normal with population mean 3 and then added points at 3.
2. The Anderson-Darling is not very sensitive to additional probability near the center (near the hypothesized mean for the fully specified test, and near the sample mean for the test with unspecified parameters; I assume you're doing the second case, such as the one in `nortest`) -- indeed it is often *biased* -- having rejection rates below the significance level when the data are less heavy-tailed about the mean than hypothesized. It's not biased in your particular case, but it does not have high power --- the rejection rate for a 5% test for an alternative like that is only about 7%. The larger p-value is likely just chance for that particular sample you added the four '3' values to.

> my first p-value is below 0.05 (confirming the hypothesis that the data is normally distributed)

- Your first p-value is above 0.05, not below it

- Failure to reject doesn't "confirm" the null.